# Entity Framework “An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker”

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I edit my object Reservation_House in following method.

```
public void ChangeAssignedMealsAndHouses(int id, NewReservation reservation)
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> item in reservation.AssignedHousesMeals)
            {
                string houseName = Regex.Match(item.Key, @"\(([^)]*)\)").Groups[1].Value;
                int houseId = db.Houses.Where(house => house.Name.Equals(houseName)).FirstOrDefault().Id;
                Reservation_House reservationHouse = (from resHouse in db.Reservation_House
                                                      where resHouse.ReservationId.Equals(id)
                                                      && resHouse.HouseId.Equals(houseId)
                                                      select resHouse).FirstOrDefault();
                reservationHouse.MealId = item.Value;
                db.Entry(reservationHouse).State = EntityState.Modified;

                ChangeAssignedHouseParticipants(reservationHouse.Id, reservation.AssignedParticipantsHouses[item.Key]);
                SaveChanges();
            }
        }
```

At some stage there is another execution of method called ChangeAssignedHouseParticipants. In this method I also modify some entity.

```
private void ChangeAssignedHouseParticipants(int reservationHouseId, List<Participant> participants)
        {
            foreach (Participant participant in participants)
            {
                db.Entry(participant).State = EntityState.Modified;
            }
        }
```

Both presented methods are in following class.

```
public class ReservationRepository : IReservationRepository
    {
        private readonly IAgrotourismContext db;
......
}
```

My context to database I obtain in this way.

```
private readonly IAgrotourismContext db;

        public ReservationRepository(IAgrotourismContext db)
        {
            this.db = db;
        }
```

I assume that this is the problem of dependency injection. Problem is during updating participants. How can I solve it?

UnityConfig.cs

```
public static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
        {
ProductRepository>();
            container.RegisterType<AccountController>(new InjectionConstructor());
            container.RegisterType<ManageController>(new InjectionConstructor());
            container.RegisterType<IUserRepository,UserRepository>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager());
            container.RegisterType<IHouseRepository, HouseRepository>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager());
            container.RegisterType<IMealRepository, MealRepository>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager());
            container.RegisterType<IAttractionRepository, AttractionRepository>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager());
            container.RegisterType<IReservationRepository, ReservationRepository>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager);
            container.RegisterType<IAgrotourismContext, AgrotourismContext>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably have problems with the configuration of the lifecycle of your objects within your IOC component. You need to configure for objects to have a lifetime while the request lasts, this will isolate the instance of your dbcontext per request. Which Dependency Injection component are you using?

Comment: Should it be configured in file UnityConfig.cs(Lifecycle of objects)?

Comment: There is ok ... You are using unity for IOC, right?
So, this article exemplifies the use of the life cycle per request ...
Http://www.wiktorzychla.com/2013/03/unity-and-http-per-request-lifetime.html

Send a piece of unity code to see how you're doing?